# Xcode : Even though iTunes Connect shows a Developer as well as distribution profile, Xcode doesn't download the Developer profile

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ad-hoc-distribution, iphone-developer-program, code-signing-certificate

Now, I have both, a Development as well as Distribution certificate when I view my Apple Developer portal at developer.com/ios . But when I view the certificates via Xcode, I just get the Distribution profile now matter what I try . Please provide a solution to get the Development profile in Xcode

- I have tried creating a Developer profile using Xcode itself, but to no success.
- I have one device added to my device List

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download the provisioning profiles and save them to somewhere you can access them. Then, double-click the profiles and certificates. This should bring up Xcode as well as Keychain. You can dismiss the windows and that should work.

In Xcode, go to build phases and check that under Development and Distribution certificates the corresponding ones are correctly filled in.